# Helpful NullPointerException in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

[JEP 358](https://openjdk.org/jeps/358) introduced helpful NPEs in Java, which is great.

Is it possible to get this working in Kotlin? I know that Kotlin goes a great deal towards avoiding NPEs - so this question is rather theoretically.

Running the following code

```
fun main() {
    val a:A? = A(null)
    a!!.b!!.c!!.n
}

data class A(val b: B?)
data class B(val c: C?)
data class C(val n: Int)
```

provides the following the output, which doesn't include any hints what might be null:

```
C:\Dev\Java\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demo.ScribbleKt.main(scribble.kt:7)
    at demo.ScribbleKt.main(scribble.kt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; Bytecode generated by kotlin do not allow the JVM to show helpful NPE.

In the section "Computing the null-detail message" inside [JEP 358](https://openjdk.org/jeps/358)

> The second part of the null-detail message is more complex. It identifies the access path that led to a null reference on the operand stack, but complex access paths involve several bytecode instructions.

If the bytecode sequence is not right and not in the valid list, the message cannot be produced. At the bottom of the list it said:

> Any other bytecode: Not applicable to the second part.

To test it, I've create 3 record classes, a Java main and a Kotlin Main.

```java
public record A(B b) {
    @Override
    public B b() { return b; }
}
public record B(C b) { ... }
public record C(int n) { ... }

public class NPEJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(null);
        int test = a.b().c().n();
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a: A? = A(null)
    val test: Int = a!!.b!!.c!!.n
}
```

The Java bytecode is pretty neat. It yields:

```
       0: new           #7                  // class com/example/A
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokespecial #9                  // Method com/example/A."<init>":(Lcom/example/B;)V
       8: astore_1
       9: aload_1
      10: invokevirtual #12                 // Method com/example/A.b:()Lcom/example/B;
      13: invokevirtual #16                 // Method com/example/B.c:()Lcom/example/C;
      16: invokevirtual #22                 // Method com/example/C.n:()I
      19: istore_2
      20: return
```

The Kotlin bytecode, however, has null checks and duplication between every invokevirtual. This is because of kotlin null safety and the usage of `!!`.

```
         0: aload_0
         1: ldc           #9                  // String args
         3: invokestatic  #15                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
         6: new           #17                 // class com/example/A
         9: dup
        10: aconst_null
        11: invokespecial #21                 // Method com/example/A."<init>":(Lcom/example/B;)V
        14: astore_1
        15: aload_1
        16: invokevirtual #25                 // Method com/example/A.b:()Lcom/example/B;
        19: dup
        20: invokestatic  #29                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNull:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        23: invokevirtual #35                 // Method com/example/B.c:()Lcom/example/C;
        26: dup
        27: invokestatic  #29                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNull:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        30: invokevirtual #41                 // Method com/example/C.n:()I
        33: istore_2
        34: return
```

Since `A`, `B`, `C` are declared in java, Kotlin does not know about null safety. In this case it is possible to not assert nullables and do exactly as the Java code do:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a: A = A(null)
    val test: Int = a.b.c.n
}
```

Executing this code do indeed show the helpful NPE.

```
Cannot invoke "com.example.B.c()" because the return value of "com.example.A.b()" is null
```

The bytecode also yields less checks.

```
         0: aload_0
         1: ldc           #9                  // String args
         3: invokestatic  #15                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
         6: new           #17                 // class com/example/A
         9: dup
        10: aconst_null
        11: invokespecial #21                 // Method com/example/A."<init>":(Lcom/example/B;)V
        14: astore_1
        15: aload_1
        16: invokevirtual #25                 // Method com/example/A.b:()Lcom/example/B;
        19: invokevirtual #31                 // Method com/example/B.c:()Lcom/example/C;
        22: invokevirtual #37                 // Method com/example/C.n:()I
        25: istore_2
        26: return
```

You would not be able to have the same behavior with data class as in your example or any Kotlin nullable field. The null safety behavior of the language would not allow helpful NPE to be shown.